# Getting Invalid Object Name ##Temp in Api execute

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, ssis, etl

I have this TEMPORAL TABLE CREATE

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##TGJAE' ) IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE ##TGJAE


SELECT
TT.RECID,
TT.TRANSDATE,
TT.DATAAREAID,
TT.SOURCERECID,
TT.SOURCECURRENCYCODE,
TT.TAXAMOUNT,
TT.TAXBASEAMOUNT,  
TT.TAXBASEAMOUNTCUR,   
TT.TAXAMOUNTCUR,   
TT.TAXORIGIN,   
TT.VOUCHER,    
TT.TAXITEMGROUP,    
TT.TAXCODE,   
TT.SOURCEBASEAMOUNTCUR,  
TT.SOURCETAXAMOUNTCUR,  
TTGJAERIVA.TAXTRANSRELATIONSHIP, 
TTGJAERIVA.GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY,  
TTGJAERIVA.LEDGERDIMENSION,
GJAERIVA.TEXT,  
GJAERIVA.LEDGERDIMENSION AS LEDGERDIMENSIONGAE, 
GJAERIVA.POSTINGTYPE 
INTO ##TGJAE

FROM TAXTRANS TT 
INNER MERGE JOIN TAXTRANSGENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY TTGJAERIVA ON TTGJAERIVA.TAXTRANS = TT.RECID

INNER MERGE JOIN GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY GJAERIVA ON TTGJAERIVA.GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY = GJAERIVA.RECID 

AND GJAERIVA.POSTINGTYPE IN( 14,236,71) 

WHERE 



(TT.TAXORIGIN <> 11 AND TT.TRANSDATE  BETWEEN dateadd(month, -18,'2017-09-01') AND '2017-09-30' ) OR (TT.TAXORIGIN = 11 AND TT.TRANSDATE BETWEEN '2017-09-01' AND '2017-09-30')
```

If I execute it in Sql Management Studio it runs correctly, but if I run from SSIS package into api, it returns

> "Invalid object name '##TGJAE'.".

can someone say me what is wrong with my package?

Comment: Because you are using global temp tables. When there is no connection open that is using a temp table it will be dropped. My guess is you are trying to find this global temp table in a separate step? The connection will be closed at the end of one step (and the global temp table along with it), then the next step runs.

Comment: @Pepe as a workaround, try implementing this code in a stored procedure, and execute it from SSIS

Comment: I solve it. as Sean comment, I open connection setting "Delay Validartion" = true and it works @Hadi

Comment: Yes, your right,  just change DelayValidation to true and it works! Thanks! @SeanLange

Comment: @SeanLange write it as answer :)

Comment: No need. Sounds like I helped steer them to the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this issue we need to keep open our connection.

To do that we just need go to properties of each `Task` or Data `Flow Task` and set `Delay Validation = true`

[image]

Comment: Cool glad I could guide you to find the solution. Good stuff.

Comment: @Pepe you have to accept this answer even if it is yours.